# Shadow Marker for Icons in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there any elegant method to add shadow markers to a loop of icons in OpenLayers 3 ?
I'm struggling with adding shadows to an icon in ol3...and there is no consistent materials about this matter.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could simple use an image (eg png) as shadow marker where the shadow is half transparent.

Comment: I had the same idea but it's not optimal in term of processing (at least in my use case). So what I'm looking for exactly is a "canvas" generated shadow...but I don't want go messy and I hope finding an "elegant" way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Try (with example styles):

```
    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 10,
            snapToPixel: false,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(77,135,254,0.4)'
            })
        }),
        zIndex: 1
    });

   var shadowStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
            width: 6
        }),
        zIndex: 0
    });

   iconFeature.setStyle([iconStyle, shadowStyle]);
```

and then:

```
        var iconSource = new ol.source.Vector(); // create an empty source 

        var icon = new ol.geom.Point( 
            // your point
        );

        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({ // create a feature
            geometry: icon
        });

        iconSource.addFeature(iconFeature); // add the feature to the source

        var iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // create a layer with that source
            source: iconSource
        });
        map.addLayer(iconLayer); // add the layer to the map
```